# Program interacting with web

Tags: c++, html, flash, bash

How or what do I need to know programming wise in order to interact with the web using c++.  For instance i want to wrote a program that automatically sends invites to players on yahoo chess.  How would i go about doing this?

Comment: There's a big leap between "interact with the web" and "send invites to players". One requires knowledge of standard HTTP and a commonly available library such as libcurl; the other requires internal knowledge of how Yahoo games work. Maybe Yahoo wants to discourage you from doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to understand the basics of TCP/IP and HTTP, possibly UDP, and the protocols involved with Yahoo's chess systems or posses a tool to work around them (A brief search leads me to believe there are few if any). You'll probably need a network API, I'd suggest looking at:

- [QtNetwork Module](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtnetwork.html)
- [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

Where Qt is easy to use, Asio is more powerful, and more 'C++' in nature. Qt has some nice webkit components, and I've used it to build a small web server, which was a lot of fun. You can accomplish quite a lot with it.

[This](http://www.yics.org/) page says they've added a captcha system to prevent certain people from interacting with their systems. I'm not familiar with Yahoo games and what the result of this has on what you'd want to do, however it suggests to me they'd rather you didn't write code to interact with their systems.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thanks for the constructure answer.

Comment: @owlstead thanks for the warm welcome, thought it was time to stop lurking :).

Answer (score -1):

For this you need to use network APIs and use server side script like PHP/ASP to communicate with the web and C using message queue.